# Unable to view graph in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to Python and practicing a tutorial using Pycharm.

I think this code is correct but i am unable to plot a graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as ml

data = pd.read_csv("C:/PythonProjects/Work/Data Science/Data/Loan_Prediction.csv")
a = data["ApplicantIncome"].hist(bins=50)
print(a.plot())
```

Comment: Try ml.show(). One cannot simply print a plot in python. Also please don't post code in the form of a screenshot always post code as formatted text in your question. That way we can easily copy past your code and run it ourselves. It makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @error states, it is not possible to print a matplotlib plot in python. Instead, you have to use the matplotlib `show()` method to display the graph.

Instead of:

```
print(a.plot())
```

Use:

```
ml.show()
```

*Adding answer to remove from unanswered category.*